# How can I add a user input with an output and be able to display using React Javascript/ Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to output something similar to this code http://jsfiddle.net/6vqd4vnq/ but need it to be in material ui/reactjs is there anything I'm missing so that the contents can be displayed like it is in the link with the js and HTML code? I'm new to react js so this is giving me some trouble. The code below is what I have and it is not displaying anything at all. I would like the output to look like the demo link that was shared.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        input1: 25000,
        input2: 30000,
        output1: '',
        output2: ''
    };

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange1(event) {
    this.setState({input1: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChange2(event) {
    this.setState({input2: event.target.value});
  }

  calculate(event) {
    this.setState({
        output1: parseInt(this.state.input1) * 4.5,
        output2: parseInt(this.state.output1) + parseInt(this.state.input2)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="{this.state.input1}"  onChange={this.handleChange1}/>
        Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="{this.state.input2}"  onChange={this.handleChange2}/>
        <button onClick="{this.calculate}">Calculate</button>

        Output1 : <input type="text" id="{this.state.output1}" />
        Output2 : <input type="text" id="{this.state.output2}" />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing pass valuye to input:

```
Output1 : <input type="text" value={this.state.output1} />
Output2 : <input type="text" value={this.state.output2} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to dig into beginner React tutorials. Your question is very unclear and lacks basic understanding of how React works.

Check React's introduction tutorial; this won't compile because it's not valid JSX code.